# Datatables search onclick event on a button

Tags: jquery, onclick, datatables

How to achieve search functionality when user click on a search button in datatables instead of onchange or onkeyup in the text boxes? Currently i am using the below code for search

```
jQuery('.asla-search-input').on( 'onkeyup change', function () {   
            var i =jQuery(this).attr('id');  // getting column index
            var v =jQuery(this).val();  // getting search input value
            dataTable.columns(i).search(v).draw();
        } );
```

But i need this search when user click on the search button. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's working for you? http://jsfiddle.net/84KNZ/63/

Comment: when i tried above i am getting "TypeError: dataTable.fnFilter is not a function" this error.I am using DataTables 1.10.4

Comment: If you use DataTables +10 you can use search function, see example https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/54/

Comment: yes, its working for single text box, but i have mulitple search options like search by id, date_from, date_to and status etc..How can i pass multiple values to search function?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding following parameters in your Datatable like this:

```
         var $oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
         "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
                        aoData.push
                        (
                            //search parameters
                            { "name": "id", "value": $('[id*="Id"]').val()},//Value of id
                            { "name": "DateFrom", "value": $('[id*="DateFrom"]').val()},//Value of DateFrom
                            { "name": "DateTo", "value": $('[id*="DateTo"]').val()},//Value of DateTo
                            { "name": "Status", "value": $('[id*="Status"]').val()}//Value of Status                          
                        )
                    },
                });        
//OnClick of your button, redraw your Datatable
        $('#btnSearch').on('click', function () {      
                $('#example').dataTable().fnDraw();
            });
```